# Dependency for Gradle build variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There are two flavours: **fl1** and **fl2**. And two buildTypes as well: debug and release. So there are four build variants: **fl1Debug**, **fl1Release**, **fl2Debug**, **fl2Release**.

How to set dependency on project only for **fl1Debug**? Or at lease for **debug** buildType?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a dependency for **debug** is pretty simple

```
debugCompile project(':lib1')
```

Comment: You can use configurations now to support fl1DebugCompile(): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/E2H_rNyO6-o/h-zFJso-ncoJ